# How to get different variable name in result instead of getting the same variable name in POJO class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using java and spring boot in my project and I am trying to get the key as "BackGround" instead of "backGround". Could you please help me to get the expected result.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
        @Entity 
        public class EmpEntity{
        
        private String backGround;
        
        }
        

        @Data
        public class EmpPojo{
        
        @JsonProperty("BackGround")
        private String backGround;
        
        }
```

Impl:

```
        ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
        EmpEntity ent=new EmpEntity();
        ent.setBackGround("value");
        EmpPojo pojo=obj.readValue(new Gson().toJson(ent),EmpPojo.class);
```

Excepted Output:

```
        {
        "BackGround":"value"
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using both jackson and gson? That overcomplicates stuff...

Comment: @JsonProperty is for Jackson library. Use Jackson instead of Gson then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonProperty` is the Jackson annotaion. For Gson you have to use `@SerializedName` from package `com.google.gson.annotations`

```
    @SerializedName("BackGround")
    private String backGround;
```